# Plain view for edit review in reopen queue

Tags: support, review, user-interface

When a closed question is edited, it gets added to the reopen review queue.  When you review the edit, the UI gives you three little sub-tabs: inline where you can see the changes highlighted in one continuous block; side by side where you can see the changes highlighted side by side, and markdown side by side.  There is nothing wrong with these views, and they are helpful.

However, in the context of reviewing if a question is good enough to reopen, it would be helpful to ignore the original edit altogether.  An example of this would be if the post was nearly entirely rewritten to narrow the scope, or if it had to be rewritten to make it clear exactly what the user was asking.  Seeing the delta between the two posts might be helpful, but it would be more helpful to have an option to just see the post as it sits.

I know I can open the post as it currently sits by opening it outside of the queue in a separate tab, but it would be significantly more convenient if I could switch to viewing it with the same sub-tabs that let me switch between inline and side-by-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is already possible. By default, the Reopen Votes queue shows you the Revision tab, which shows the most recent revision as it would appear in the revision history (including the style options). If you just want to look at the question itself, not the revision, you need to click on the Question tab, which is up higher on the page.

[image: View the question]